# Усложненная задача на поиск острова с максимальной площадью и плодородностью

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, рекурсия

Фермер Василий выбирает землю для покупки. Предмет торгов – прямоугольное поле шириной n и высотой m, которое состоит из участков, где 1 - плодородный участок, а 0 – неплодородный. Василий может либо купить регион поля любого размера, либо отказаться от покупки, если доступных для покупки регионов нет.

Условия покупки следующие:

– Регион – это прямоугольник, ограничивающий соприкасающиеся участки плодородной почвы

– Участки "соприкасаются" если они соседние друг для друга – сверху, снизу, справа, слева **и по диагонали**

1  0  1

0  1  1

1  0  1

0  0  0

0  1  0

На примере выше соприкасаются все участки, кроме нижнего, то есть регионов здесь 2, один площадью 9, другой площадью 1

– Регионы могут пересекаться между собой:

1 1 1 1 1

1 0 0 0 1

1 0 1 0 1

Здесь тоже два региона, один площадью 15 (все поле), другой площадью 1

– Минимальное количество плодородных участков в регионе для покупки – 2

– Покупатель платит только за общую площадь купленного региона

Василий берет кредит на покупку, поэтому хочет потратить деньги как можно оптимальнее – купить тот регион, в котором будет максимальное соотношение плодородной земли к общей площади региона. Если есть несколько регионов с одинаковой «эффективностью», то Василий хочет купить бóльший из них по площади.

Нужно определить площадь региона, который стоит купить фермеру

Входные данные (поступают в стандартный поток ввода)
Первая строка – целые числа n, m через пробел (2≤n≤100, 2≤m≤100)

Далее m строк, в каждой из которых по n цифр 0 или 1, разделенных пробелами

Все входные данные наших тестов всегда соблюдают указанные параметры, дополнительные проверки не требуются

Выходные данные (ожидаются в стандартном потоке вывода)
Одно целое число, площадь наилучшего региона, или 0, в случае отказа от покупки

**Пример 1**

Ввод:

5 4

0 1 1 0 0

1 1 1 0 1

1 1 0 0 1

0 0 0 1 0

Вывод:

9
На этом поле доступны для покупки:

Первый регион для покупки

Левый верхний угол с координатами [0, 0]
Правый нижний угол с координатами [2, 2]
Его площадь 9, а плодородных участков на нем 7.
Эффективность покупки этого региона рассчитывается как 7/9

Второй регион поля для покупки

Левый верхний угол с координатами [3, 1]
Правый нижний угол с координатами [4, 3]
Его площадь 6, а плодородных участков на нем 3.
Эффективность покупки этого региона рассчитывается как 3/6

7/9 > 3/6, поэтому Василию стоит купить первый регион.

**Пример 2**

Ввод:

5 3

1 1 1 0 1

1 1 1 0 1

1 1 1 0 1

Вывод:

9

Здесь эффективность регионов одинакова – они оба полностью заполнены плодородной землей, но регион слева больше, поэтому ответ 9

```
public class MaxIsland {
public static void main(String[] args) {

var map = new int[][]{
new int[]{1,1,1,0,1},
new int[]{1,0,0,0,1},
new int[]{0,1,0,1,1},
new int[]{1,0,0,1,1}
};
System.out.println(maxAreaOfIsland(map));

}

private static int horizon = 0;
private static int vertical = 0;
public static int maxAreaOfIsland(int[][] grid) {
int width = 0;
int high = 0;
int maxArea = 0;
for (int r=0; r<grid.length; r++){
for (int c=0; c<grid[0].length; c++){
if (grid[r][c] == 1){
int area = expand(grid, r, c, 1, 1,1);
maxArea = java.lang.Math.max(area, maxArea);
}
}
}
return maxArea;
}

private static int expand(int[][] grid, int r, int c, int area, int width , int high){

if (r<0 || c<0 || r>=grid.length || c>=grid[0].length || grid[r][c]!=1)
return 0;
horizon += width;
vertical += high;

grid[r][c] = 0;
area += expand(grid, r + 1, c, 1 ,1 ,0);
area += expand(grid, r - 1, c, 1, 1, 0);
area += expand(grid, r, c + 1, 1, 0 ,1);
area += expand(grid, r, c - 1, 1, 0 ,1);
area += expand(grid, r + 1, c + 1, 1, 1, 1);
area += expand(grid, r + 1, c - 1, 1, 1, 1);
area += expand(grid, r - 1, c + 1, 1, 1, 1);
area += expand(grid, r - 1, c - 1, 1, 1, 1);

return area;
// Math.max(horizon, vertical);
}
```

Уже что то нарешал, но столкнулся с проблемой подсчета площади. При проходе по диагонали в разные стороны постоянно ширина увеличивается и посчитать площадь не могу.

Comment: объясните тугому, а за шо минусы у парня? Тип много букав, нет конкретики? АА читать сложна?

Comment: Просто перебери все прямоугольники и выдели регионы. Критерии региона: 1) прямоугольник 2) все внешние участки - нулевые 3) на каждой стороне есть хотя бы один ненулевой участок.

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato мой минус за то, что это учебная задачка, а не реальная задача, к которой есть простыня условия (намекающая на "сделайте за меня"). Также не видно попыток отладки и минимального воспроизводимого кода с четкой ошибкой. Ну и в целом в таком виде вопрос выглядит бесполезным для Базы Знаний. Вы, кстати, я вижу, плюс тоже не поставили

Comment: @Kromster Да, это учебная задача. Код находится снизу страницы, там же указал, где именно у меня трудности. Я думал, что не обязательно заниматься обучением ИИ, чтобы получить помощь на сайте?!

Comment: При чем тут обучение ИИ? ) Вы просто задали вопрос с огромной простыней условия не относящейся к конкретной озвученной проблеме - *"При проходе по диагонали в разные стороны постоянно ширина увеличивается"* и не потрудились ни сделать Минимальный Воспроизводимый Пример Кода, ни заняться базовой отладкой алгоритма "на бумаге".

Comment: @Kromster про ии было к >мой минус за то, что это учебная задачка, а не реальная задача<
Простыня условия нужна, потому что условия задачи отличаются от обычной задачи на поиск площади острова, причем в нескольких моментах. В этом и заключается сложность и то, что у меня не получается.

Comment: На всякий случай напомню, что кроме автоматической проверки checkup будет также очное собеседование, как уже несколько раз упоминалось в разборах заданий школы программистов на хабре. Если вы чувствуете, что сами не справляетесь – лучше взять годик перерыва и прокачаться.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш подход к вычислению площади региона не годится, ведь одни и теже площади учитываются много раз

Рекурсивный вызов должен возвращать не площадь, а крайние координаты - левую, правую, верхнюю, нижнюю, и количество правильных клеток.

Вызывающая функция объединяет по минимуму левые и верхние границы, по максимуму правые и нижние. На самом верхнем уровне, когда весь регион уже обошли, вычисляется площадь и эффективность